# Disabling Customizer Selective Refresh shortcut icons for selected controls

Tags: theme-development, customization, theme-customizer

Sometimes, on using the selective refresh feature, the shortcut looks little meaningless when an element is sort of removed from the view.

[image: Extra Shortcut Icon showing with freshly-loaded content]

For example, if I remove the custom logo and replace it with the Title and description text, the edit icon for the custom logo remains along with the title and the description text, which looks a bit too much.

```
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'custom_logo', array(
  'selector'        => '.site-logo',
  'render_callback' => 'the_custom_identity',
  'container_inclusive' => true,
) );
```

I went through the WP_Custom_Selective_Refresh::add_partial() method, there is no option for opting out from showing those shorcut-icons. Can someone guide us more in this regard please? Thanks.